# jQuery slider help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I made a slider, but i'm not that great with jQuery. I would like to pause the slider on hover, and also would like to prevent the buttons from being used when an animation is playing. Can anybody help me with this?

```
var jq = $.noConflict();

setInterval(function() {
      var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
      if(leftPos == 5400){
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 800);
      }else{
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 900}, 800);      
      }
},  3000);

      jq('.rightarrow').click(function() {
      var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
      if(leftPos == 5400){
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 800);
      }else{
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 900}, 800);      
      }
   });

      jq('.leftarrow').click(function() {
      var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
      if(leftPos == 0){
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: 5400}, 800);
      }else{
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 900}, 800);
     }
   });
```

This is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/apielotje/2kyaJ/958/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** fixed bug on arrows.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/r5norvwu/)

Is this what you want? I just hid the buttons when the animation is played, and when a hover is detected they are shown again. If you want the buttons can just be disabled instead of hidden.

```
var jq = $.noConflict();

var siId = -1,
    si = function () {
        //hidding buttons
        siId = setInterval(function () {
            var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
            if (leftPos == 5400) {
                jq('#browser').animate({
                    scrollLeft: 0
                }, 800);
            } else {
                jq('#browser').animate({
                    scrollLeft: leftPos + 900
                }, 800);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }

//hidding arrows initially
jq('.rightarrow, .leftarrow').hide();

jq('#scrolldiv_container').mouseenter(function(){
    jq('.rightarrow, .leftarrow').show('fast');
    clearInterval(siId);
})
jq('#scrolldiv_container').mouseleave(function(){
    jq('.rightarrow, .leftarrow').hide('fast');
        si();
});

jq('.rightarrow').click(function () {
    var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
    if (leftPos == 5400) {
        jq('#browser').animate({
            scrollLeft: 0
        }, 800);
    } else {
        jq('#browser').animate({
            scrollLeft: leftPos + 900
        }, 800);
    }
});

jq('.leftarrow').click(function () {
    var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
    if (leftPos == 0) {
        jq('#browser').animate({
            scrollLeft: 5400
        }, 800);
    } else {
        jq('#browser').animate({
            scrollLeft: leftPos - 900
        }, 800);
    }
});

//starting slider here
si();
```

Comment: @user3733479 I noticed a bug. You can't access the arrows with my script. Here is an update: https://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/r5norvwu/

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean to see if the user hovers the `#scrolldiv_container` element.

```
var isHovering = false;
setInterval(function() {
    if(!isHovering) {
        var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
        if(leftPos == 5400){
            jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 800);
        } else{
            jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 900}, 800);      
        }
    }
},  3000);
```

Add events for mouseenter and mouseleave o the `#scrolldiv_container` element. This way it won't scroll when you're hovering the left and right buttons. It's not the exact thing you asked for but I'd be satisfied with the end result.

```
jq( "#scrolldiv_container" ).mouseenter(function() {
    isHovering = true;
    }).mouseleave(function() {
    isHovering = false;
});
```

Read about the events here: https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j5sqjfvk/

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a function and manage your intervals on hover. This  Will pause the slider on hover. And You can also control fading of buttons in the hover section.

```
    var jq = $.noConflict();
     function test() {  //name your function
      var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
      if(leftPos == 5400){
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 800);
      }else{
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 900}, 800);      
      }
     }

     var interval = setInterval(test, 3000); //set default interval

      jq('.rightarrow').click(function() {
      var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
      if(leftPos == 5400){
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 800);
      }else{
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 900}, 800);      
      }
   });

      jq('.leftarrow').click(function() {
      var leftPos = jq('#browser').scrollLeft();
      if(leftPos == 0){
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: 5400}, 800);
      }else{
      jq('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 900}, 800);
     }
   });
   jq('#scrolldiv_container').hover(function(){
    clearInterval(interval); //destroy interval on hover
     },         
    function(){
     interval = setInterval(test, 3000); // create default interval on hover out
    });
```